# Flutter Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

````
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `background_fetch` from `.symlinks/plugins/background_fetch/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `connectivity` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_for_web` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_for_web/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `connectivity_macos` from `.symlinks/plugins/connectivity_macos/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `devicelocale` from `.symlinks/plugins/devicelocale/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `esys_flutter_share` from `.symlinks/plugins/esys_flutter_share/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_crashlytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install --verbose
```

### Report

* What did you do?

* What did you expect to happen?

* What happened instead?


### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.9.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.4 (19E287)
       Xcode : 11.4.1 (11E503a)
         Git : git version 2.20.1
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : master - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ cee826cdfd82e8ad63f23d532e519f8248a09ce7

               trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.4.1
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0
```

### Podfile

```ruby
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  # Flutter Pod

  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'  # required by simple_permission
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'

      # Here are some configurations automatically generated by flutter

      # You can remove unused permissions here
      # for more infomation: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
         'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        #'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
         'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        # 'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
         'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
         'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
      ]

    end
  end
end

pod 'Firebase/MLVisionFaceModel'
```

### Error

```
ArgumentError - Malformed version number string p.0
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/version.rb:47:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:199:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:199:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/vendor/version.rb:192:in `create'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/platform.rb:54:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:517:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:517:in `block in available_platforms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:517:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:517:in `available_platforms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:402:in `dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/validator.rb:44:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:201:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:201:in `validator_for_podspec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:186:in `validate_podspec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/abstract_external_source.rb:178:in `store_podspec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:17:in `block in fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:980:in `fetch_external_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:959:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:958:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:958:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:957:in `fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:117:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Malformed+version+number+string+p.0&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - Error running pod install Error launching application on iPhone 11.
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9981 [closed] [1 comment]
   16 Aug 2020

 - error when running pod install
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9195 [closed] [4 comments]
   04 Oct 2019

 - 0.38.1: Linker errors due to incompatible semver versions
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3887 [closed] [10 comments]
   25 Jul 2015
````

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/ashraf/Desktop/Work/App.Connect/smile_me_in in PATH, mode 040757

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You should uncomment your profile ios target.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
```

If it also doesn't work. You need to check your target device's minimum support os version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ios/Pods/Local Podspecs folder of your flutter application, check the highest ios platform target required by each Podspec then go to ios/Podfile, uncomment the line that defines the ios platform target and change it to the highest found in your Podspec