# Flutter: build failed iOS running pod install

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to build iOS Flutter app. It throwns me this error:

https://pastebin.com/NG6EWWcj

`Error running pod install`

Comment: Please make sure that your question is self-contained. Everything that we need to answer the question should be contained within the question's body, not on external sites.

Answer (score 0):

Your logs show two errors

First

> ```
> Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
> ```

This tells you that if you want to use `cloud_firestore`, you will have to increase your minimum iOS version requirement. The process to do that is explained [here](https://flutteragency.com/steps-change-minimum-ios-deployment-target/) e.g.

> ```
>   [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
> ```

This question has already been answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213663/flutter-automatically-assigning-platform-ios-with-version-9-0-on-target-run).

Answer (score 0):

Run this command
arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update