# Flutter build ios failing with: Error running pod install

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

When I run `flutter build ios` I get this failed output:

```
Running pod install...                                             471ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A firebase_dynamic_links
      A path_provider_ios
      A share_plus
      - Flutter
      - app_tracking_transparency
      - cloud_firestore
      - firebase_analytics
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - google_sign_in_ios
      - purchases_flutter
      - shared_preferences_ios
      - sign_in_with_apple
      - url_launcher_ios

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `app_tracking_transparency` from `.symlinks/plugins/app_tracking_transparency/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
    firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_dynamic_links` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_dynamic_links/ios`
    firebase_dynamic_links: Using Firebase SDK version '10.1.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `google_sign_in_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/google_sign_in_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `purchases_flutter` from `.symlinks/plugins/purchases_flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `share_plus` from `.symlinks/plugins/share_plus/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `shared_preferences_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences_ios/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sign_in_with_apple` from `.symlinks/plugins/sign_in_with_apple/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `url_launcher_ios` from `.symlinks/plugins/url_launcher_ios/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo
      update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
      performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo
      update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/2.30909.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
      performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_d_4_0.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo
      update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/d/4/0/GoogleSignIn/6.2.4/GoogleSignIn.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is
      only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_9_a_d.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo
      update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/9/a/d/PurchasesHybridCommon/4.3.1/PurchasesHybridCommon.podspec.json exists! Returning local
      because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/9.3.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
      performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/Firestore (= 9.3.0)

      In Podfile:
        cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
          Firebase/Firestore (= 10.1.0)

    Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Firestore (= 9.3.0), Firebase/Firestore (= 10.1.0)` dependency were found, but they required a
    higher minimum deployment target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1078:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
```

Whats odd is I was running builds for a few weeks no problem. I had to update some plugins inside the pubspec.yaml file then it all broke when building ios

I immediately googled my answered and found this stack overflow question here: [Flutter Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213663/flutter-automatically-assigning-platform-ios-with-version-9-0-on-target-run)

They mentioned to:

> You should uncomment your profile ios target.

I had already had that un-commented and set to `platform :ios, '11.0'`

I then did some more research and it looks like it could be a Mac M1 Chip issue: [How to run CocoaPods on Apple Silicon (M1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64901180/how-to-run-cocoapods-on-apple-silicon-m1/65334677#65334677)

I followed the 2022 instructions there:

```
# Uninstall the local cocoapods gem
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

# Reinstall cocoapods via Homebrew
brew install cocoapods
```

This failed and I think brought me into a bigger hole so I ran `flutter doctor`

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on macOS 12.5 21G72 darwin-arm, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
    ! CocoaPods 1.5.2 out of date (1.11.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart
        side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

I then clicked on the link and followed the instructions to update cocoa pods.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
Fetching cocoapods-core-1.11.3.gem
Fetching cocoapods-1.11.3.gem
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.11.3
Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-core-1.11.3
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-core-1.11.3
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-1.11.3
Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-1.11.3
Done installing documentation for cocoapods-core, cocoapods after 2 seconds
2 gems installed
```

But if I run flutter doctor again, it still says its out of date...

Think I am in a worse place now.

Comment: Could you restart your mac, run "gem which cocoapods" and tell me the output? This will check which kind of cocoapods is currently installed. And restarting/relogging might be helpful to load the newly installed version

Comment: On further thought, I would suggest a complete deinstallation and reinstallation of cocoapods. It seems to me that you have two conflicting versions (one via "brew install ..." and one via "gem install"). You can use "gem uninstall cocoapods" and "brew uninstall cocoapods" to uninstall. Afterwards, run flutter doctor again to verify there is no installation present. Then reinstall via gem install.

Comment: I would assume that you have an outdated brew version which causes you to load an old version (1.5) of cocoapods. Might be worth to run brew update / brew upgrade

Comment: @jraufeisen tried all that then had issues trying to run brew update: https://pastebin.com/PnPJtPig

Comment: Try the gem command with sudo in front of them. So "sudo gem uninstall cocoapods". For the brew error, try "rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)" followed by "brew tap homebrew/core". More info on the brew problem here: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/1512

Comment: so looks like I got back on track with cocoapods: https://pastebin.com/4Vz8J1hh

Still having issues now with flutter build ios which gave me this: https://pastebin.com/rmNuUXjE

Then I ran: pod repo update but I still get build error after

Comment: I am running pod update Firebase/Firestore 

Right now. Its takign awhile but fingers crossed this fixes it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize a few keypoints here:

1. Your `cocoapods` installation was broken. So try removing the brew version first via "brew uninstall cocoapods" Then install cocoapods via `sudo gem install cocoapods`.
2. Your `Podfile` is referencing two different versions of the same package.

```
  [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/Firestore (= 9.3.0)
 
      In Podfile:
        cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 4.0.5, which depends on
          Firebase/Firestore (= 10.1.0)
```

This might also cause the build error. You could try to find versions of the plugins `snapshot` and `cloud_firestore` that don't conflict with one another.

Comment: thanks for all the help. Attempting this right now:

 You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Firestore` inside your development pod `cloud_firestore`.
       You should run `pod update Firebase/Firestore` to apply changes you've made.